# Groovy sql to byte

Tags: postgresql, groovy, arrays

I have to get a document that's stored in a postgres database and put it into a byte array.

In Java this works just fine

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn1.prepareStatement("SELECT document FROM documents WHERE documentname = ?");
ps.setString(1, "dingbatdocument.docx");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    byte[] documentBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
}
```

but I have to use groovy for this code and know nothing about how to do it, so far I've tried this

```
def newSpelling = "dingbatdocument.docx";
def val = sql.execute("SELECT document FROM documents WHERE documentname = ?", [newSpelling]) as byte[];
```

and get this error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'byte'
at    korg.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:146)
```

which to me says it is trying to asset that it has worked rather than giving me and actual byte array,

and this

```
def newSpelling = "dingbatdocument.docx";
byte[] val = sql.execute("SELECT document FROM documents WHERE documentname = ?", [newSpelling]);
```

and get this error:

```
Groovy script throws an exception of type class org.postgresql.util.PSQLException with message = This ResultSet is closed.
```

and finally this:

```
  def reqdColName = "document";
  def reqdDocument = "dingbatdocument.docx";
  def query1 = "SELECT $reqdColName FROM documents WHERE documentname = '$reqdDocument'";
  def documentBytes = conn1.executeQuery(query1).getArray(reqdColName);
```

which also gives me

```
Groovy script throws an exception of type class org.postgresql.util.PSQLException with message = This ResultSet is closed.
```

So my question is how do I get the same result in groovy as I do in java, a byte[] variable from my sql resultset?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was quite easy, but not knowing Groovy it's different.  Here is how I did it in the end,

```
  def reqdColName = "document";
  def reqdDocument = "documentName.docx";
  def query1 = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE documentname = '$reqdDocument'";


  byte[] myData;
  conn1.eachRow(query1){
      row ->      
      if(debug){logger.severe(dI+thisTrace+"myData \n"
         +"\t"+row.documentid+"\n"
         +"\t"+row.documentname
         +"\t"+row.versionmajor +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.versionminor +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.versionmini +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.uploader +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.approver +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.uploaddate +"\n"
         +"\t"+row.approvaldate +"\n"
//       +"\t"+row.document+"\n"
         );}
      myData = row.document
  }
```

myData is the byte[] repesentation of the document I needed.